# How to retrieve an array pass in the key value of a dictionary in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I fill a table "weekInfos". I assign it to the value of a key "week" of a dictionary "dicoWeek".
I have to miss something simple but I do not understand why nothing is displayed in the debug part.

Could you, please, help me understand my mistake?

```
Sub test()
   Dim allCuid As Range, weeks As Range, week As Range
   Dim iCol as Long
   Dim weekInfos(6)

   Set dicoWeek = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   For Each week In weeks
      For iCol = 0 To 5
         weekInfos(iCol) = .Cells(week.Row, iCol + 7).Value
      Next iCol
      weekInfos(iCol) = .Cells(week.Row, 15).Value
      dicoWeek.Add Key:=week.Text, Item:=weekInfos
      Debug.Print dicoWeek(Str(week.Text))
   Next week
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Why are you creating it in a loop? `Set dicoWeek = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`? and what is `weeks` in `For Each week In weeks`

Comment: weeks is a range from an excel table containing week numbers.

Comment: Indeed, I moved the creation of my dictionary but it does not work better .... smile

Comment: Nothing is displayed because it is containing an array. Try using `Debug.Print Join(dicoWeek(Str(week.Text)), ", ")`

Comment: You're also missing a `With` block meaning your `.Cells` won't have the correct reference. Which sheet should these be looking at? Also, what is `weeks`? It isn't defined here

Comment: Maybe post the actual code rather than something that wouldn't even run?

Comment: Do you have option explicit  at the start of each module, your code suggests you don't  You say weeks is an excel table defined elsewhere BUT you have defined a local variable weeks therefore the weeks you are using in the for loop is not the weeks containing the excel table  you have defined eslewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is more what I'd expect to see in your code - This is a working example. You should update `With ActiveSheet` to a proper reference of your working `Sheet` and change the `Set weeks = Range("A1:A5")` to your actual range

```
Sub test()
    Dim allCuid As Range, weeks As Range, week As Range
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim dicoWeek As Object
    Dim weekInfos()

    Set dicoWeek = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet
        Set weeks = Range("A1:A5")

        For Each week In weeks
            ReDim weekInfos(0 To 6)

            weekInfos = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(week.Row, 7), .Cells(week.Row, 11)).Value2))
            ReDim Preserve weekInfos(LBound(weekInfos) To UBound(weekInfos) + 1)

            weekInfos(UBound(weekInfos)) = .Cells(week.Row, 15).Value
            dicoWeek.Add Key:=week.Value2, Item:=weekInfos

            Debug.Print Join(dicoWeek(week.Value2), ", ")
        Next week
    End With
End Sub
```

I'd also advise to remove any variables that aren't used in your routine e.g. `allCuid`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The double "Application.transpose" is it better than for loop ?.In fact, I also missed the declaration of weekInfos () as Variant. it works perfectly well.

Comment: @ChristopheC. The double transpose is just a quick way of getting a 1D array from a range. The for loop would work equally as well and save having to ReDim Preserve the array.